# Reject ICMP request

Tags: c, network-programming, winsock2, icmp

I created ICMP client/server app. Client start by sending an ICMP request package(I created the `ipHeader` and `icmpHeader`) and server answer by an ICMP reply. And every thing work fine.
So my question is: How can the server reject the ICMP request.

I tried to send from the ICMP server a "Destination Unreachable package" answer but when I check the client I found that he received "echo reply package" (`code = 0 , type= 0 and data = empty`).

Comment: It's not clear what you really want to acheive. Do you want your server app to discard ICMP request? Or you want you OS to do that for you? Which OS you're using?

Comment: Yes i want my server app discard ICMP request

Comment: Did you made the necessary modification on your server code to do that?

Comment: Lets give you more details: I created the client side which create the ipHeader, icmpHeader next send the package to the server

 nRet = sendto(objRawSocket,(const char*)&echoReq,sizeof(objSockDest));

And in the server side just i receive and i answer to the client with icmp "Destination Unreachable" package(code=7 , type =3)

But the client receive each time echo reply .

Comment: Ok, it seems you're getting the reply from windows ICMP stack. Hmm... now you can try to disable sending ICMP echo request from windows, but the problem is it might discard the ICMP packet altogather which might not reach your server app.

Comment: I disable the icmp echo request from windows but i got again "echo reply" in the client :(

Comment: Did you properly disabled ICMP echo reply from windows firewall option, ie. Windows inbound option?

Comment: I edit the windows Inbound rules by adding new rules which block echo reply but the my client receive echo reply.

Comment: To make sure whether ICMP echo reply is blocking properly or not you can use 'ping'. See whether you get any reply from ping req or not.

Comment: Sorry if obvious, but double-check you are pinging correct address:)

Comment: when i ping from another computer i did not get reply. that mean that in windows echo reply is block. But my client still receive echo reply. I will try to execute my client from another computer.